# Get the pairs of values from a list according to a condition without elements repeating

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I have a list of integers like:
1 3 4 4 9 7 10  (the number of elements is between 1 and 200000)
and an integer variable D, it lies between 0 and 10^9.
Let it be 5 for example.

I need to count how many pairs in the list have a difference between each other not bigger than a variable D but **the tricky part is** that if I took the zero element with value 1 and the first element with the value 3(the difference between them meets the condition) I can't use these elements of a list again.

For example for the sequence above the answer is 3 pairs: (1,3) (4,4) (7,9)

I wrote a code which seems to be correct but I need a hint how to change the input sequence and the variable d the way it will output wrong answer

```
    list_of_colors = [1, 3, 4, 4, 9, 7, 10]
    d = 5

    number_of_pairs = 0

    list_of_colors.sort() # the values in the list are not always sorted

    i = 0 
    while True:
        if i >= len(list_of_colors): 
            break
        if i != len(list_of_colors) - 1:  
            # if the number i in list and i+1 is the same or difference between them not greater than a variable d...
            if (int(list_of_colors[i]) == int(list_of_colors[i + 1])) or abs(int(list_of_colors[i]) - int(list_of_colors[i + 1])) <= d:
                #print list_of_colors[i]," ",list_of_colors[i + 1]
                number_of_pairs += 1 # increasing the number of the acceptable pairs  
                i += 2  # jump over two elements, we already counted them
                continue
        i += 1

    print number_of_pairs
```

I need another algorithm to compare it with the results of my algorithm on the various range of the input sequence and the variable d

Suggest your ideas please

Comment: `itertools.combinations(list_of_colors, 2)` function in `itertools` library gives  you all not repeated combinations. But I think, it's not efficient way to solve this problem

Comment: Yes it does but it will output all the 21 possible combinations for the example above and the answer is 3 pairs not 21 because I cant use the elements of the list I've already used.

Comment: This question is not well-posed.  If my list is 1, 2, 3, 4, and D is 1, then one solution is (1, 2), (3, 4), but another solution is (2, 3).  Are you looking for the *maximum* number of disjoint pairs whose difference is at most D?

Comment: Amit Kumar Gupta Sorry If I didn't make it clear. I need a **maximum** number of possible combinations without repetitions of them(not values but the exact elements of  the list) in the next pairs which difference is not greater than D. In your example the answer is 2 pairs. Another example: if my list is 1,2,3,4,5,7 and D is 1 the answer is 2 pairs:(1,2) (3,4). yes the last pair can be (4,5) but it doesn't matter because I need a maximum number

Answer (score 0):

I have a greedy solution for this problem:

Sort the input sequence.

Parse the sorted sequence as follows:

```
For ith element in the sequence, 
  if |a[i+1]-a[i]| <= D, 
     then pair up the elements. Proceed to process i+2th element.
  else
     proceed to process i+1th element.
```

Comment: This code concept is the same as mine with the exception of my unnecesarry check int(list_of_colors[i]) == int(list_of_colors[i + 1]). The abs(int(list_of_colors[i]) - int(list_of_colors[i + 1])) <= d is enough for checking the condition d.

Answer (score 0):

My solution here is to first "clean" the list what means I made the number of elements even. Then I've converted the list into a list of tuples (pairs).
My result for this example is 3 pairs in order to your condition.

```
list_of_colors = [1, 3, 4, 4, 9, 7, 10]
d = 5
number_of_pairs = 0
list_of_colors.sort() # the values in the list are not always sorted

# remove the last element if the number of elements is odd
if len(list_of_colors) % 2 != 0:
    list_of_colors = list_of_colors[:-1]

# create a list of tuples
list_of_colors = [tuple(list_of_colors[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(list_of_colors), 2)]    

for i in list_of_colors:
    if (int(i[0]) == int(i[1])) or abs(int(i[0])) - int(i[1]) <= d:
        number_of_pairs += 1

print number_of_pairs
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code won't work for the following case: 1,3,4  and the d is 1. Your code will return 0 and the actual answer is 1(tuple (3,4) meets the  condition)